# 市区町村より小さいエリアのgeojsonが欲しい

Tags: javascript

市区町村より小さいエリア情報を持つgeojsonが欲しいのですが、どこかにございませんでしょうか。
番地レベルまであればありがたいです。

もしくは自作の方法があればお教えいただけませんでしょうか。

よろしくお願いします。

Comment: 自己解決しました。http://www.e-stat.go.jpにて国勢調査に用いられた境界データがshpファイルで配布されており、それをgeojsonに変換することができました。ありがとうございました。

Answer (score 3):

自己解決しました。https://e-stat.go.jp にて国勢調査に用いられた境界データがshpファイルで配布されており、それをgeojsonに変換することができました。ありがとうございました。

<sub>-- [質問者](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/users/25393/%E3%82%B9%E3%82%B3%E3%83%9A%E3%83%83%E3%82%BD%E3%82%B9)さんの[コメント](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/37955/%E5%B8%82%E5%8C%BA%E7%94%BA%E6%9D%91%E3%82%88%E3%82%8A%E5%B0%8F%E3%81%95%E3%81%84%E3%82%A8%E3%83%AA%E3%82%A2%E3%81%AEgeojson%E3%81%8C%E6%AC%B2%E3%81%97%E3%81%84#comment38227_37955)をCommunity wikiとして再投稿したものです。</sub>

Answer (score 1):

[overpass-turbo](http://overpass-turbo.eu/) を使って OpenStreetMapより特定エリアのノード情報を取得してみてはいかがでしょうか。

[overpass-turbo](http://overpass-turbo.eu/) はWebベースのOSMデータのマイニングツールで、データを取得為に [専用クエリ](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/JA:Overpass_API)を記述する必要がありますが、今回のような特定エリアのノードデータを全て取得するだけであれば簡単に記述できます。

具体的な方法としては

1. 右側の地図を、データを取得したいエリアを表示している状態にする
2. 左側のテキストエディタ部に下の２行を記述

   node({{bbox}});
   out;
3. 上側の「実行」ボタンを押す（しばらく待つ）
4. 取得できたノードが地図上に表示されるので、上側の「エクスポート」ボタンを押す。
5. データの形式"GeoJSON"で "download" する

です。

> あまり広い範囲を選択すると、膨大なデータになり処理時間もそれなりにかかりますので、最初は狭い範囲から確認してみることをお勧めします。